# RegEx to Match Some Literal "\par" NewLine and a bracket

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have an rtf formatted text below where each rtf always contains "\par newline and a bracket}"

Is there a RegEx that can find and replace/remove the last occurrence of "\par" before any "}".

Input Text

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Consolas;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue255;}
{\*\generator Riched20 6.2.9200}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\ltrpar\tx720\cf1\highlight2\f0\fs19 FocusedTextControl.TextElementReadOnly = \cf3 false\cf1 ;FocusedTextControl.TextElementReadOnly = \cf3 false\cf1 ;FocusedTextControl.TextElementReadOnly = \cf3 false\cf1 ;FocusedTextControl.TextElementReadOnly = \cf3 false\cf1 ;FocusedTextControl.TextElementReadOnly = \cf3 false\cf1 ;\highlight0\f1\fs22\par
}
```

Required result without the \par

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Consolas;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue255;}
{\*\generator Riched20 6.2.9200}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\ltrpar\tx720\cf1\highlight2\f0\fs19 FocusedTextControl.TextElementReadOnly = \cf3 false\cf1 ;FocusedTextControl.TextElementReadOnly = \cf3 false\cf1 ;FocusedTextControl.TextElementReadOnly = \cf3 false\cf1 ;FocusedTextControl.TextElementReadOnly = \cf3 false\cf1 ;FocusedTextControl.TextElementReadOnly = \cf3 false\cf1 ;\highlight0\f1\fs22
}
```

Since I'm using c# it looks like this might do it too:

```
        string parR = @"\par";
        var s = content.LastIndexOf(parR, System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
        var n = content.Remove(s, parR.Length);
```

instead of doing it this way:

```
  Regex r = new Regex(@"\\par\r");
  r.Match(content);
  var s =r.Replace(content, string.Empty);
```

Comment: I tried \\par\r it didn't work.  It seems that \\par\r\} will do the trick. Just that there are NUL char between \par and }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there some reason this regex doesn't work?

`\\par\}`

Just replace it with `\}`

(Notice the backslash escapes, because both `\` and `}` are special characters in regex.)

Comment: this did the trick.. \\par\r\} however for some reason i found out there are NUL chars between \par and }

Comment: To make escaping even easier you can do `Regex.Escape(@"\Par}")`. [`Regex.Escape(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) will escape all characters that Regex would interpret as a special character.